# How do we get the true labels to calculate the accuracy using accuracy_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried Calculating accuracy score for my testing prediction value but how will I get the value of `y_true` in the below equation?
I mean `y_pred` is attained using:

```
clf_predict(features_test,labels_test)
```

but what about `y_true`? Is there any specific way that we get this.

```
sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y_true` is the variable containing the class/labels that your algorithm is trying to predict for your test set.
I assume that you are facing a supervised learning problem: in that case, `y_true` is known and contained in your test set.

Using your conventions:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(features_test) #without labels_test!
accuracy_score(labels_test, y_pred)
```